# pray for recently passed away parent

Tags: death, kaddish, shema

I am not an observant Jew but I was confirmed and bar mitzvahed in a reform synagogue. I want to pray for my father who passed away 10 days ago. I would like to pray several times a day or more if possible, especially for the next 20 to 30 days. I don't live anywhere near where a minyan could be assembled. I live in a remote area of Japan. I cannot read Hebrew anymore. I have an affinity for orthodox Judaism but don't practice it. I do have a Siddur from Rabbi Shneur Zalman of Liadi. Is there a prayer I can say often during the day? How often is it OK to say the Shema? What restrictions are there on saying the Shema? Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: onyourmark,  [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887). I'm so sorry for your loss; may you be comforted among the mourners of Zion and Jerusalem. [We aren't set up to offer you personal spiritual advice.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) I recommend that you contact a rabbi and discuss your situation and desires with him, so you can get personalized guidance. There may be no rabbis in your immediate neighborhood, but Google indicates that there is at least one in Tokyo; I strongly suspect that if you reach out, they'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will  do as you suggest, speak with a Rabbi, say the Shema, read the Psalms and try to become familiar with the Amida. The Amida in the Siddur I have seems to be for festivals but I will search on the internet for a regular one.

Comment: Google to get an Art Scroll siddur in Hebrew and English, such as http://artscroll.com/Books/9780899066509.html

Comment: @onyourmark get in touch with the nearest shul and ask to read the mourner's kaddish (which requires a minyan). I help run a shul in a fairly remote part of Peru, and a similar request from someone living in an even remoter part of our region galvanized the entire community, brought people from two different shuls together and resulted in us having a minyan on a regular Friday night for the first time anyone can remember. A mitzvah for all involved

Comment: @onyourmark May you be comforted among the mourners of Zion and Jerusalem...  I'm really sorry your question was put on hold. Please stick around and ask more questions. An immensely difficult time like this is a great time to turn to G-d. Maybe this is even why we are given difficult times. Our ancestors, through years of effort and, frankly, love, found a way to serve G-d that is durable, valuable, and life-sustaining. It's worth following now and for the rest of your life. Please read Herman Wouk's This Is My G-d and find an Orthodox rabbi and shul near you; I suggest Chabad, where you will

Comment: [...] find people ready and eager to help beginners and returnees as well as those who have faced loss. If you ask the rabbi there to learn with you,  say, every week, you can pick up the skills you lost. It should be in a good hour. https://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/9318/jewish/Global-Directory.htm

Comment: @onyourmark Also, if I'm not mistaken, you can say the Shema at any time of day and as often as you like.  Gut Shabbos

Comment: Thank you all for the kind comments and suggestions. I did the Amida today. It is the first time I have done it by myself. In the past, I may have done it at a synagogue.  I have also decided to go to Tokyo for the latter part of this month to be with the rabbi. I have a question. There are websites online that will do Kaddish for my father for a year for a fee. I found that Chabad.org offers this service. Can I go ahead with this? I want to. Of course, I want to do it myself but I can only be in Tokyo infrequently. Thank you.

Comment: I am learning the Amida here: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/980653/jewish/Audio.htm